# How to set an event for every other Wednesday in Laravel

Tags: laravel, command, scheduled-tasks

Laravel has a lot of options for artisan commands scheduling but I've been trying to get one to run every other Wednesday and haven't find the right combination of functions, do any of you have an idea on how to achieve this, did you test it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well crons can be specified to run on certain days of the week.
Using Laravel's scheduler you could start running it every Wednesday like this:

**app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('foo')
        ->wednesdays()
        ->when(function () {
            return Carbon::now()->weekOfYear % 2 == 0;
        });
}
```

edit: using the `when` function as suggested in the comments is prettier. It has all time logic in 1 place.

Comment: I'll try to concatenate it using the when() function